# identify multiple links within UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` and I have multiple Links within my webpage from which I want to open the links depending on which links are clicked, I want to perform different actions on different links, point is how I can identify different links? I am using

```
 if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        //link clicked... but which one?

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out which url is clicked by using the `request.URL` and check what is the link you are clicking by using `rangeOfString` method as I show under

```
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

     if ([[request.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"http://firstLink"].location!=NSNotFound){
            //perform your action..
     } else if ([[request.URL absoluteString]rangeOfString:@"http://secondLink"].location!=NSNotFound){
        /// perform action for second link..
      }    
  }
```